# CSS HTML tfoot, tbody, thead complex styling

Tags: html, css, html-table

Can I use `<thead>` inside `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>` apart from main `<thead>` of `<table>`?

I would like to style thead inside main components differently, but I don't understand, why higher specifity some of them does not react and some styles works on every `<tr>` while I specified it only to `<tbody>`.

I would like to try do it without classes.

Here is simple example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
body {
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

table > thead   {background-color: pink;} /*0002 - to main thead*/   
table > tbody > thead > tr > th {background-color: skyblue; } /*0005 - to "Final students marks" and "Avarage marks in groups"*/


tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC;} /*0011*/
tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF;} /* why it styling tfoot?? */

tfoot tr:nth-child(even) {background: sandybrown !important; /*why not work???*/ }
tfoot tr:nth-child(odd) {background: sandybrown !important;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
     <thead> 
      <tr><th>Number</th><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th><th>Group</th><th>Mark</th></tr>
     </thead>
                    
     <tbody>
      <thead><tr><th colspan="5">Final students marks</th></tr></thead>
                        
      <tr><td>1</td><td>Adam</td><td>Abacki</td><td>A</td><td>4</td></tr>
      <tr><td>2</td><td>Ewa</td><td>Babacka</td><td>B</td><td>5</td></tr>
      <tr><td>3</td><td>Edward</td><td>Cabacki</td><td>A</td><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>4</td><td>Tomasz</td><td>Dadacki</td><td>A</td><td>4</td></tr>
      <tr><td>5</td><td>Anna</td><td>Kowalska</td><td>B</td><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>6</td><td>Marek</td><td>Zawadzki</td><td>A</td><td>5</td></tr>
     </tbody>
                    
     <tfoot>
      <thead><tr><th colspan="5">Average marks in groups</th></tr></thead>
                        
      <tr><td>1</td><td colspan="2"></td><td>A</td><td>4</td></tr>
      <tr><td>2</td><td colspan="2"></td><td>B</td><td>4</td></tr>
     </tfoot>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the final effect, which I would like to have:
[image: Expected look of table]

Comment: If you used a [validator](https://html5.validator.nu/) to help check and correct your mark-up, you'd understand why.

Comment: Can you add a picture of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Here you are @BryceHowitson

Comment: Can any one explain downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`<thead>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead)

> Permitted content: Zero or more `<tr>` elements.
>
> Permitted parents: A `<table>` element.

So your table structure should be:

```
table
  thead
    tr
      th
  tbody
    tr
      td
  tfoot
    tr
      td
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table>thead {
  background-color: pink;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table>tbody>tr:first-child>td,
table>tfoot>tr:first-child>td {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

tbody>tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #CCC;
}

tfoot>tr {
  background: sandybrown;
}

tbody>tr>td:first-child,
tfoot>tr>td:first-child {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Group</th>
        <th>Mark</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Final students marks</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Abacki</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Ewa</td>
        <td>Babacka</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Edward</td>
        <td>Cabacki</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Tomasz</td>
        <td>Dadacki</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Anna</td>
        <td>Kowalska</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Marek</td>
        <td>Zawadzki</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Average marks in groups</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove thead inside tfoot, tbody and use only tr and th and add pink color background

**Note** : thead and tfoot elements can be used once in a table.

```
    tbody > tr > th, tfoot > tr > th {background-color: skyblue !important; } /*0005 - to "Final students marks" and "Avarage marks in groups"*/

tbody > tr > td:first-child, tfoot > tr > td:first-child {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

code sample for reference

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

table > thead   {background-color: pink;} /*0002 - to main thead*/   


tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC;} /*0011*/
tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF;} /* why it styling tfoot?? */

tfoot tr:nth-child(even) {background: sandybrown !important; /*why not work???*/ }
tfoot tr:nth-child(odd) {background: sandybrown !important;}

tbody > tr > th, tfoot > tr > th {background-color: skyblue !important; } /*0005 - to "Final students marks" and "Avarage marks in groups"*/

tbody > tr > td:first-child, tfoot > tr > td:first-child {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<table>
     <thead> 
      <tr><th>Number</th><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th><th>Group</th><th>Mark</th></tr>
     </thead>
                    
     <tbody>
      <tr><th colspan="5">Final students marks</th></tr>
                        
      <tr><td>1</td><td>Adam</td><td>Abacki</td><td>A</td><td>4</td></tr>
      <tr><td>2</td><td>Ewa</td><td>Babacka</td><td>B</td><td>5</td></tr>
      <tr><td>3</td><td>Edward</td><td>Cabacki</td><td>A</td><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>4</td><td>Tomasz</td><td>Dadacki</td><td>A</td><td>4</td></tr>
      <tr><td>5</td><td>Anna</td><td>Kowalska</td><td>B</td><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>6</td><td>Marek</td><td>Zawadzki</td><td>A</td><td>5</td></tr>
     </tbody>
                    
     <tfoot>
<tr><th colspan="5">Average marks in groups</th></tr>
                        
      <tr><td>1</td><td colspan="2"></td><td>A</td><td>4</td></tr>
      <tr><td>2</td><td colspan="2"></td><td>B</td><td>4</td></tr>
     </tfoot>
    </table>

</body>
```

codepn - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jQwWPm

Answer (score 1):

`thead` Isn't valid inside of tbody (yes they're just tags but tables are from a different time with different browser rules). You CAN use multiple `tbody` tags to group things and `css:first-child` to color rows correctly.

```css
body {
   background-color: black;
   text-align: center;
   color: black;
  }
thead {
 background-color: pink;
}

tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {
 background: #CCC;
}
tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {
 background: #FFF;
}
/* remove important or other colors won't work */
/* just place AFTER other definition in CSS */
tbody:nth-child(3) tr {
 background: sandybrown;
}
/* place this after other definition to make everything blue */
tbody>tr:first-child {
 background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Group</th>
    <th>Mark</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="5">Final students marks</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>Abacki</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Ewa</td>
    <td>Babacka</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Edward</td>
    <td>Cabacki</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Tomasz</td>
    <td>Dadacki</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Anna</td>
    <td>Kowalska</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>Marek</td>
    <td>Zawadzki</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>5</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="5">Average marks in groups</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>4</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>

</body>

</html>
```